# openssl key for drush

Tags: drush, ssl

My server does not allow passwords and requires me to setup an openssl key for access. Drush however requires the server to be more open and I wonder how to setup an openssl key or some other option for using drush update features.

Comment: Do you mean SSH key?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Drush runs ssh with the option `-o PasswordAuthentication=no`, which prohibits username/password access and requires that you use a public/private key pair to access your server.  This is exactly what you want, and in fact, by default, ssh will use the private key that it finds at $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa to authenticate you with remote servers.

If you need to use some other private key, though, you can put this line in your drushrc.php file:

```
$options['ssh-options'] = '-o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /home/YOURUSERNAME/.ssh/other_id_rsa';
```

Note that Drush will not automatically evaluate bash shortcuts such as $HOME or ~.  If you do not want to hardcode the path to your home folder, you may look it up with `$HOME = drush_server_home();`.